# Where should i modify my tree traversal code to avoid Unknown signal 11 error?

Tags: python-3.x, tree

This tree traversal is a bit different due to the nature of its input, perhaps this pictorial presentation, would bring more clarity :

for the input :

```
5 # no of nodes 
# key left-child  right-child
4 1 2 # key 4 has left-child as key 2(index 1) and right-child as key 5(index 2)
2 3 4
5 -1 -1 # key 5 has no children thus both sides are assigned -1 
1 -1 -1
3 -1 -1
```

the  output tree seems like :

[image]

The task in hand was to create a tree and output the inorder, preorder and postorder traversal of nodes

**Problem :** many test-cases pass without fail, but few test-cases output a message : *unknown signal 11*, it doesn't exceed the memory limit as well as time limit for those test-cases i have checked, what exactly is *unknown signal 11*, and why does it arise ?

**what i tried :** many online forums advised to increase the stack-size which i did too, yet the same message was displayed.

**what i want :** Any suggestions as to where should i modify my code and why ?

My code :

```
import sys, threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)  # new thread will get stack of such size(i increased it upto size 31)


def preord(root, adic):

    if root != -1:
        k = adic[root]
        print(k[0],end = ' ')

        preord(k[1], adic)

        preord(k[2], adic)

def postord(root, adic):

    if root != -1:
        k = adic[root]
        postord(k[1], adic)

        postord(k[2], adic)

        print(k[0],end = ' ')

def inord(root, adic):

    if root != -1:
        k = adic[root]
        inord(k[1], adic)

        print(k[0],end = ' ')

        inord(k[2], adic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())# no of nodes
    adic = []
    for _ in range(n):
        ro, l, r = map(int, input().split())# accepts key and it's children
        adic.append([ro, l, r])
    inord(0, adic)
    print()
    preord(0, adic)
    print()
    postord(0, adic)
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run only `inord`? `preord`? `postord`? Let try narrow down the problem

Comment: That's sort of difficult to check because the test cases are not known to me and also they check the solutions for all traversals altogether

Comment: Can it be case where root not first row? can be a case where this tree has cycle? (graph) Can it be case when `n` = 0? Your logic seem solid

Comment: I tried all of your guesses...it was good though to do that check but no that's not the case... I guess I have to do now in iteration method tree traversal

Comment: Maybe try check `if root != -1 and isset(adic[root])` (or what ever the syntax for isset is in python3.x

Comment: isset checks if a variable is defined or not right ?

Comment: Yes -or just as: `if root in adic:`

Comment: Root is an index in adic right.